# How to determine if a string contains any element of a set

Tags: scala

I have a sentence, and I want to determine if it contains any elements of a set.

```
val sentence = "Hello, today is a fine day to learn scala"
val mySet = Set("day", "scala")
```

Comment: If you need to test only by words _(case insensitive)_ you can do: `sentence.split("\\w+").exists(word => mySet.contains(word.toLowerCase))`

Answer (score 4):

What about:

```scala
mySet.exists(word => sentence.contains(word))
```

It will return `true` if at least one word from the set is present in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that...

- is case-**in**sensitive (`"scala"` **does** match `"Scala"`)
- ignores sub-strings (`"rat"` does **not** match `"rats"`)
- ignores punctuation (!?,-) unless specifically specified in `mySet`

```
mySet.mkString("(?i)\\b(", "|", ")\\b")
     .r.unanchored
     .matches(sentence)
```